# I get this error when I was running npm i in terminal

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I get this error when I was running npm i in terminal

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "react-datepicker " of package "react-datepicker @^4.8.0": name cannot contain leading or trailing spaces; name can only contain URL-friendly characters.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-13T10_31_02_808Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: works fine for me: `npm i -S react-datepicker`....what command did you run?

Comment: also you have a space in the package name. Read the error message.

Comment: yeeh I didn't notice her thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the error. You can't use space in npm installation. there is a space between package name and version number.
use this command

```
react-datepicker@^4.8.0
```

instead of

```
react-datepicker @^4.8.0
```

Comment: but where i can find this error i didn't do any thing i just writ npm i in trminal

Comment: look your package.json file.